# Inserting an XML node using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I seem to be stuck in implementing an "XML data insert using Javascript".

My application is an asp.net with asp.net AJAX.

My XML document is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hotels>
    <hotel supplier="Sarova panafric" id="HTL-10001">
        <supplier>Sarova panafric</supplier>
        <contact>Mr S Njoroge</contact>
        <tel>75-525254</tel>
    </hotel>
    <hotel supplier="Sarova mara" id="HTL-10002">
        <supplier>Sarova mara</supplier>
        <contact>Mr ole seni</contact>
        <tel>20-54574</tel>
    </hotel>
</hotels>
```

This is the JavaScript function I use to try and insert data in my XML file:

```js
function addhotels() {
    var xml;
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xml.open("GET", "hotelRates.xml", true);
    xml.send(null);

    var hotel = xml.responseXML.createElement("hotel");

    var supplier = xml.responseXML.createElement("supplier");
    supplier.appendChild(xml.responseXML.createTextNode("Sarova stanley"));

    var contact = xml.responseXML.createElement("contact");
    contact.appendChild(xml.responseXML.createTextNode("Mr Njoroge"));

    var tel = xml.responseXML.createElement("tel");
    tel.appendChild(xml.responseXML.createTextNode("21454741"));

    hotel.appendChild(supplier);
    hotel.appendChild(contact);
    hotel.appendChild(tel);
    xml.responseXML.appendChild(hotel);
}
```

The XML file is sitting on the root folder of my project, where pages are located.

I don't know why it doesn't work.

==============================
I have now changed the code as follows, but still no effect.

```js
function addhotels() {
    var xml;
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xml.open("GET", "hotelRates.xml", true);
    xml.send(null);

    var hotels = xml.responseXML.createElement("hotels");

    var supplier = xml.responseXML.createElement("supplier");
    supplier.appendChild(xml.responseXML.createTextNode("Sarova stanley"));

    var contact = xml.responseXML.createElement("contact");
    contact.appendChild(xml.responseXML.createTextNode("Mr Njoroge"));

    var tel = xml.responseXML.createElement("tel");
    tel.appendChild(xml.responseXML.createTextNode("21454741"));

    hotels.appendChild(supplier);
    hotels.appendChild(contact);
    hotels.appendChild(tel);
    xml.responseXML.appendChild(hotels); 
}
```

Comment: You are *still* doing `xml.responseXML.appendChild`. You cannot append to the document itself, as mentioned in both answers below.

Answer (score 2):

You're currently invoking `send` and then expecting the response to be immediately available. This is fundamentally wrong. The third argument to `xml.open` (`true`) indicates that you want the request to be executed asynchronously. You need to handle the response in an `xml.onreadystatechange` callback:

```
function addhotels() {
    var xml;
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
            var resp = xml.responseXML;
            var hotel = xml.responseXML.createElement("hotel");

            var supplier = xml.responseXML.createElement("supplier");
            supplier.appendChild(xml.responseXML
                    .createTextNode("Sarova stanley"));

            var contact = xml.responseXML.createElement("contact");
            contact.appendChild(xml.responseXML.createTextNode("Mr Njoroge"));

            var tel = xml.responseXML.createElement("tel");
            tel.appendChild(xml.responseXML.createTextNode("21454741"));

            hotel.appendChild(supplier);
            hotel.appendChild(contact);
            hotel.appendChild(tel);
            xml.responseXML.documentElement.appendChild(hotel);
        }
    }
    xml.open("GET", "hotelRates.xml", true);
    xml.send(null);
}
```

Note that I also changed `xml.responseXML.appendChild` to `xml.responseXML.documentElement.appendChild` as pointed out by @Dr.Molle. You can't append to the document itself.

Comment: Thank you lwburk, I will try and notify you on the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
xml.responseXML.documentElement.appendChild(hotel);
```

Currently you append the node to the document, what is an illegal operation because an XML-document may only have 1 root-element.
`xml.responseXML.documentElement` points to the root-element(`<hotels/>`)

Comment: A **big** problem is going to be the fact that he's launching an asynchronous request and then expecting the response to be ready immediately ...

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't look at this. But when he will fix that he must consider my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you are not saving the changes made. You need to save it to the XML file. You could first take the response XML as variable xmldoc, then add the new data into it and at last write- xmldoc.save("hotelrates.xml");