# Add a new element in an existing local XML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I have an existing XML file containing data like the following.
I want to add a new book, with title, author, year and price.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bookstore>
    <book category="children">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book category="web" cover="paperback">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: Are you using the javascript environment of a web browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting an XML node using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511104/inserting-an-xml-node-using-javascript)

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, actually I'm going to use an HTML form, but give me a solution with static data using Javascript and I'll figure it out.

Comment: @hifebriansyah It didn't work to me.

Comment: I found many solutions via the search. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340894/create-xml-in-javascript/34047092#34047092) looks promising

Answer (score 0):

here,working code sample

```
 function XMUpdate() {
    try {
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    }
    catch (e) {  try { xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);  }
    catch (e) { }
    }
    try {
        xmlDoc.async = false;
        xmlDoc.load("C:/test.XML");
        newEle = xmlDoc.createElement("book");

        newEle1 = xmlDoc.createElement("Title");
        newText1 = xmlDoc.createTextNode("aaaa");
        newEle1.appendChild(newText1);
        newEle.appendChild(newEle1);

         newEle2 = xmlDoc.createElement("author");
        newText2 = xmlDoc.createTextNode("SSSSSS");
        newEle2.appendChild(newText2);
        newEle.appendChild(newEle2);

        newEle3 = xmlDoc.createElement("year");
        newText3 = xmlDoc.createTextNode("2019");
        newEle3.appendChild(newText3);
        newEle.appendChild(newEle3);

        newEle4 = xmlDoc.createElement("price");
        newText4 = xmlDoc.createTextNode("39.95");
        newEle4.appendChild(newText4);
        newEle.appendChild(newEle4);

        xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("bookstore")[0].appendChild(newEle);
        xmlDoc.save("C:/test.XML");
    }
    catch (e) { alert(e.message) }
    return (null);
}
```

Comment: It shows an alert saying "xmlDoc.load is not a function"

Comment: above code will work ony in Internet explorer(supports ActiveX controls).Google Chrome and Firefox web browsers do not support ActiveX controls by default.

Comment: Still didn't work in Internet Explorer, it says "Object doesn't support  property or method  'load'".
Do you have a solution for Google Chrome, a translation to your code.

Answer (score 0):

See below (adding a book and title). Hit the 'Demo' button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function demo() {
var parser, doc;
var text = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bookstore>
    <book category="children">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book category="web" cover="paperback">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>`;

parser = new DOMParser();
doc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

var book = doc.createElement("book");
book.setAttribute("category", "other");
book.setAttribute("cover", "nice");
let title = doc.createElement("title");
let title_txt = doc.createTextNode("the new title");
title.appendChild(title_txt);
book.appendChild(title)
doc.getElementsByTagName("book")[0].appendChild(book);

alert(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc.documentElement))
}


</script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="demo()" value="Demo">


</body>
</html>
```